# Orthogonal Projections and Orthogonal Bases

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have come across this idea over and over but cannot understand why it is true.

For an inner product space $A$ over the field $K$, where $B \subset A$ and a fixed $\{b_1 ... b_n\}$ is an orthogonal basis for $B$, the projection of any $a \in A$ onto $B$ is independent of the choice of $\{b_1 ... b_n\}$.

The explanations I've found use these properties of $A$ and $a$.

$A = B \oplus B^{\perp}$

$a = b + (a-proj_{B}a)$

I'm confused by how a discussion about the basis of a subspace relates to the idea of larger inner product space. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the definition that you use for projection?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824429/prove-that-projection-is-independent-of-basis/1826039#1826039)?

Comment: @yohBS The definition I'm using for projection is $proj_{B}a= \langle a,b_{1} \rangle b_{1} +...+ \langle a,b_{n} \rangle b_{n}$. Also, my apologies to the person whose comment I think I just deleted! I'm still figuring out how to use the site! Their question was about the definition for $b$; it's a vector in $B$.

Comment: @lthompson You didn't delete my comment.  I just realized that you probably meant $b+(\color{red}{a}-\operatorname{proj}_Ba)$.  Also that definition only works for an orthonormal basis $\{b_i\}$.

Comment: @Bye_World Thank you for the link to that other question. It looks like they're asking the same thing! I remain confused about the proof given in the answer, especially between the second and third steps: How does $((v - w_{1} )-(v - w_{2} )) \perp W \Longrightarrow (w_{2} - w{1} ) \perp W$?

Comment: @Bye_World Also, thank you for the correction. I've changed it in the above.

Comment: $$\require{cancel}((\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{v}}}-w_1)-(\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{v}}}-w_2)) = -w_1--w_2 = w_2-w_1$$

Comment: @Bye_World Oh goodness, my apologies for the oversight. Thank you again for sharing that question and for clarifying. I think it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Recall from Calculus that you defined the orthogonal projection of a point $\vec{p}$ onto a line or a plane is the unique point $\vec{q}$ on that line or plane such that $\vec{q}-\vec{p}$ is orthogonal to the line or plane. The orthogonal projection and the closest point projection are the same.

Orthorthogonal projection generalizes to any dimension of inner product space $X$. Specifically, if $M$ is a subspace of $X$, then the orthogonal projection of $x \in X$ onto $M$ is the unique $m\in M$ such that $(x-m)\perp M$. And a closest point projection $m'\in M$ of $x$ onto $M$ is the unique $m'\in M$ such that $\|x-m'\| \le \|x-m\|$ holds for all $m\in M$. It turns out that the closest point projection of $x$ onto $M$ exists iff the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ exists, and these two are the same if they exist. If $M$ is finite-dimensional, then the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ exists for all $x\in X$ because it may be constructed using an orthonormal basis $\{ e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n \}$ of $M$; indeed, the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ is $P_Mx = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j$. More generally, if $M$ is a complete subspace of $X$, then $P_M$ exists.